# Excluding/Filtering using word count

Tags: powershell

I am totally new to PowerShell and I am trying to find a way to filter a set of data in Active Directory through word count and based on all of my research, I have not found anything relevant to me except for `Name.length`. I was looking for something more like `Word.length`. For example:

**What I have:**

```
Get-ADUser -filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties Name | sort-object name | select-object Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*Admin*" -and $_.Name "*hotdog*" }
```

**What I would like:**

```
Get-ADUser -filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties Name | sort-object name | select-object Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*Admin*" -and $_.Name "*hotdog* -and **$_.Name -ne "1 word"**}
```

Comment: To put it into simple terms...You want to find all users whose name does not contain the word "Admin" but does contain the word "hotdog" and is at least 2 words?

Comment: Hi, to clarify, I would like to find all users whose name contain more than 1 word. 

For example, if it says phonenumber instead of phone number, then I would want to exclude phonenumber only.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ADUser -filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties Name | sort-object name | select-object Name | Where-Object { $wrds=$_.Name.Split(" "); $_.Name -notlike "*Admin*" -and $_.Name "*hotdog* -and wrds[1] }
```

Create an array wrds that gets created from splitting names based on a space as a separator. Then check to see if the second index of the wrds array exists (name has more than one word)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Name` property is returned by default for the Get-ADUser cmdlet, you do not have to specify that as extra property.

This uses regex to filter out the names you want filtered out, and also to split the names on Non-Word characters in order to find out if the name consists of multiple words.

```
# combine the words to exclude with regex OR ('|')
# if they contain regex special characters, you need to escape them first using [regex]::Escape()
$excludeThese = 'Admin|hotdog'

Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch $excludeThese -and (($_.Name -split '\W').Count -gt 1) } |
    Select-Object Name | Sort-Object
```